# Insert an Image from the gallery on a button in Android

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-button

Im trying to do this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        b[1].setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, new BitmapDrawable(bmp), null, null);
}
```

But it wont set the image, no matter what. I have tried several different methods too, like using an imagebutton instead of a button and using:

```
imageButton.setImageBitmap(bmp)
```

The gallery opens fine and and the callback comes to onActivityResult(...)
but the image wont appear on the button, I have an array of buttons.

Comment: But the image won't appear on the button... You want to appear the image on the button??

Comment: Yes, I want the image to be on the button.

Comment: have you tried ImageButton.setImageUri(selectedImage)? I'm not sure if it can handle content provider uris, though.

Comment: I have been stuck on this since the past 3 days, doesnt anyone know the solution, or prod me in the right direction???

Comment: that decodeFile() method is deprecated, did you try `decodeFile(getResources(), picturePath)`? (use @bigstones to notify me that you answered)

Comment: @bigstones decodeFile wont take those arguments..

Comment: Oops sorry, that was `BitmapDrawable(getResources(), picturePath)`!! I don't know what else to say. Try to find where is the problem (it's a long way from the URI to the button), so at least try to see if the bitmap is correctly created (could that be null?), and what happens if you set another drawable on the button.

Comment: @bigstones bitmap is not null, Iv debugged that piece like a million times with different methods, However I want to ask you, is there a wau to convert the URI into a resourceID, I know it sounds stupid..But this implementation is imperative to the project...

Comment: I used `BitmapDrawable(getResources(), picturePath)` doesn't work http://postimage.org/image/slpt1oe8l/ a link with the debug screenie, showing bitmapdrawable is not null!

Comment: @bigstones can you think of anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a rapid test. The following code works for me. If with this you still can't set the image I would check if there's a layout problem (i.e. the image is set but there's no room to show it).

activity_main.xml has just an ImageButton set to wrap_content, inside the main layout which is match_parent.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton imgButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton);

        imgButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");

                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RESULT_CANCELED) return;

        ParcelFileDescriptor fd;
        try {
            fd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd.getFileDescriptor());

        imgButton.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I think there is a layout problem, but I kinda dont understand, if an image is to be set on a button,It should be set , right? the images are shown perfectly if i use a resource image instead of a gallery image..

Comment: @ChaitanyaPantar: if it works with resources, the problem is not in the layout, and I don't think it can be the images one chooses. Have you tried my code for loading the bitmap? it works here (tested on emulator, android 2.2).

Comment: I tried your method to no avail.. Im actually using an array of buttons (because I have text to display too along with the image on the button) like in my snippet above, but i converted them all to imagebuttons, still nothing.. Oh man.. BTW im testing this code on galaxy tab 10.1. Would you like to take a look at a pastebin of my class?